# Why am I getting a timeout error when exporting a mariadb connection pool in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, mariadb

**EDIT**

I found the error. The mistake was very obvious: I did not include the
`require("dotenv").config();` in the connection.js file. Without this, the database connection simply fails after a timeout because it does not have any connection details.
I found an update log from the Mariadb Node.js connector team stating they have a few errors where Mariadb does not provide sufficient error messages (it sometimes only offers a "timeout" without further information), so I changed what I was looking for, and found the mistake.

For anyone getting a similar error message, this can mean anything, so check all parts of your code!

**Original Post**

I am trying to get familiar with Nodejs and express, but ran into an issue that I can't seem to solve:

When creating a Mariadb database pool in a seperate file, and exporting the pool using module.exports, I am having trouble using the same pool in another file. I get a timeout error when trying to use the pool to query a database.

If I use the exact same code in the same file instead of two separate files, the query works perfectly, so I think there is something going wrong during module.exports = pool.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

I have two files:
**index.js**:

```
// import express web framework
const express = require("express");

//create an express application
const app = express();

const pool = require('./database/connection')
const cors = require('cors');

//middleware
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

getData = async () => {
    data = await pool.query("call stored_procedure")
    console.log (data)
}

getData()

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Serving running on port 3001')
})
```

and **connection.js**:

```
//import mariadb library
const mariadb = require("mariadb")

//function that create mariadb connection pool for database
const createPool = () => {
    try {
        return (
            mariadb.createPool({
                connectionLimit: 10,
                host: process.env.MARIADB_HOST,
                user: process.env.MARIADB_USER,
                password: process.env.MARIADB_PASSWORD,
                database: process.env.MARIADB_DB,
                port: 3306
            })
        )
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to database: ')
        console.error(err)
    }
}

const pool = createPool()

//export database connection pool
module.exports = pool
```

Running this app results in the following error (after some time):

```
path_to_dir/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:57
  return new SqlError(msg, sql, fatal, info, sqlState, errno, additionalStack, addHeader);
         ^

SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms
    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)
    at Object.module.exports.createError (path_to_dir/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:57:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (path_to_dir/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:345:26)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  text: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms\n' +
    '    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)',
  sql: null,
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The mistake was very obvious: I did not include the require("dotenv").config(); in the connection.js file. Without this, the database connection simply fails after a timeout because it does not have any connection details. I found an update log from the Mariadb Node.js connector team stating they have a few errors where Mariadb does not provide sufficient error messages (it sometimes only offers a "timeout" without further information), so I changed what I was looking for, and found the mistake.

For anyone getting a similar error message, this can mean anything, so check all parts of your code!